# How do you use numpy array's to color pixels?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, python-imaging-library

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import os.path
import numpy as np

directory = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
filename = os.path.join(directory, "woman.jpg")

img = plt.imread(filename)
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)
ax.imshow(img, interpolation = "none")

img = img.copy()
img.setflags(write = 1)

height = len(img)
width = len(img[0])
for i in range(420, 475):
    for j in range(135, 160):
        img[i][j] = [0, 255, 0]

fig.show()
```

This is supposed to color a certain area of pixels green, but it does nothing to the original pixels

Comment: "but it does nothing to the original pixels" - well, yes; what do you suppose `img = img.copy()` is doing? Also, did you try making the changes *before* the `imshow` call?

Comment: Try calling `imshow` after you set the pixel color.